# TypeError: cannot assign 'torch.cuda.FloatTensor' as parameter 'weight_hh_l0' (torch.nn.Parameter or None expected)

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to train the model implemented in this repo https://bitbucket.org/VioletPeng/language-model/src/master/ (the second model: title to title-storyline to story model)

The training would go fine for the first epoch, but as soon as it tries to call the train function to start the second epoch everything breaks and I get the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot assign 'torch.cuda.FloatTensor' as parameter 'weight_hh_l0' (torch.nn.Parameter or None expected)
```

I don't know what the issue is, I tried looking this error up and tried changing .cuda to .to(device) and using device= inside the tensor initialization when possible.

But none of this seems to be doing anything.

Below is the full exception stack trace:

```
  File "pytorch_src/main.py", line 253, in <module>
    train()
  File "pytorch_src/main.py", line 209, in train
    output, hidden, rnn_hs, dropped_rnn_hs = model(data, hidden, return_h=True)
  File "/home/e/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/e/Documents/Amal/language-model/pytorch_src/model.py", line 81, in forward
    raw_output, new_h = rnn(raw_output, hidden[l])
  File "/home/e/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/e/Documents/Amal/language-model/pytorch_src/weight_drop.py", line 47, in forward
    self._setweights()
  File "/home/e/Documents/Amal/language-model/pytorch_src/weight_drop.py", line 44, in _setweights
    setattr(self.module, name_w, w)
  File "/home/e/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 108, in __setattr__
    super(RNNBase, self).__setattr__(attr, value)
  File "/home/e/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 801, in __setattr__
    .format(torch.typename(value), name))
```

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded my python to 3.6 and reinstalled all the requirements and it worked.

So probably the issue was an incompatible torch version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of PyTorch require parameters as torch.nn.Parameter.
I think you need to change the code as follows, at least, it helped me with the same error in the code based on the same codebase:

```
def _setweights(self):
    for name_w in self.weights:
        raw_w = getattr(self.module, name_w + '_raw')
        w = None
        w = torch.nn.functional.dropout(raw_w, p=self.dropout, training=self.training)
        setattr(self.module, name_w, torch.nn.Parameter(w))
```